# Is making a parameter non-optional a binary-backwards compatible change?

Tags: c#, backwards-compatibility, optional-parameters

I am adding a new optional parameter to a function and I want to maintain binary backwards compatibility. The old API is:

```
public void Foo(string message, object data = null) { ... }
```

The new API is:

```
// maintained for backwards compat
public void Foo(string message, object data) { Foo(message, data, null); }

public void Foo(string message, object data = null, TimeSpan? time = null) { ... }
```

The reason I need to drop the default value for data in the old API is that otherwise a call to Foo("a") is ambiguous. I don't want to require the data parameter in the new method since a common use-case is to do `Foo(message, time: time)`. Similarly, I don't want to have to switch parameter order going forward since the order in my real code makes a lot of sense.

Is this binary backwards compatible (ignore reflection which might access ParameterInfo.DefaultValue)? My thought is that, since the optional parameter is dealt with at compile-time, there is no difference between not passing the paramter and passing it in the IL. For example, the following LinqPad code:

```
void Main()
{
    A(0);
    A();
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public int A(int a = 0) { return a; }
```

Produces the following IL for Main():

```
IL_0001:  ldarg.0     
IL_0002:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0003:  call        UserQuery.A
IL_0008:  pop         
IL_0009:  ldarg.0     
IL_000A:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_000B:  call        UserQuery.A
```

Thus, it looks like there's no difference. However, I'm not sure what exactly goes into binary compatibility. For example, does the compiled code keep some reference to the expected signature of UserQuery.A if it's defined in another assembly?

Answer (score 3):

Yes; that is backwards-compatible.